# How to manage several "localhost" entries in ssh/config that only differ by port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

So, I am operating in an environment where ssh is extremely limited. My simplest way to do anything is to actually channel ssh through a tunnel over aws session manager.

So, here is a sample configuration

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host thetaone
  HostName localhost
  User ssm-user
  LocalForward 11000 localhost:22
  LocalForward 5800 localhost:5800
  ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --profile thetaone --target i-xxxxxx --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession
Host prod
  HostName localhost
  User myuser
  LocalForward 12000 localhost:22
  ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --target i-yyyyy  --profile prod --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession
Host github.com
  HostName localhost
Host dev
  HostName localhost
  User myuser
  LocalForward 10000 localhost:22
  ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --target i-zzzz   --profile dev --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession
Host sb
  HostName foo.bar.org
  User someuser
  ProxyJump thetaone
```

However, if I run:
`ssh prod`
and then later
`ssh dev`

I get an error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:ceTPAuYIJfG++YZ8Si4oyxDSekKnAsKmL64cPP8sXRI.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:19
Host key for localhost has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

so, how can I effectively tell ssh that a "host" definition is actually "host:port" - or, maybe there is a mechanism entirely different to address this. Obviously I can edit the allowed_hosts file, but I want something seemless

Answer (score 1):

A `HostKeyAlias` should help.

```
Host dev
  HostName localhost
  HostKeyAlias localhost-dev
Host prod
  HostName localhost
  HostKeyAlias localhost-prod
```